# How to use rownames_to_column with dates

Tags: r, tidyverse, xts

I am trying to convert my yahoo price downloads to a "tidy" format, but in the reprex below, the dates lose their format and are converted to rownumbers.  Stated differently, how do I convert from xts to tibble and preserve the dates?

```
prices <- getSymbols("QQQ", adjustOHLC = TRUE, auto.assign = FALSE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Date")
head(prices)
```

Comment: Or use the tidyquant package. Then everything is returned in tibbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it in all in a single tidyverse pipe, simply convert to a data frame first:

```r
library(quantmod)
library(tibble)

getSymbols("QQQ", adjustOHLC = TRUE, auto.assign = FALSE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Date") %>%
  as_tibble()

#> # A tibble: 3,419 x 7
#>    Date       QQQ.Open QQQ.High QQQ.Low QQQ.Close QQQ.Volume QQQ.Adjusted
#>    <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 2007-01-03     43.5     44.1    42.5      43.2  167689500         38.3
#>  2 2007-01-04     43.3     44.2    43.2      44.1  136853500         39.1
#>  3 2007-01-05     44.0     44.0    43.5      43.8  138958800         38.9
#>  4 2007-01-08     43.9     44.1    43.6      43.9  106401600         38.9
#>  5 2007-01-09     44.0     44.3    43.6      44.1  121577500         39.1
#>  6 2007-01-10     44.0     44.7    43.8      44.6  121070100         39.6
#>  7 2007-01-11     44.7     45.2    44.7      45.1  174029800         40.0
#>  8 2007-01-12     45.0     45.3    45.0      45.3  104217300         40.2
#>  9 2007-01-16     45.3     45.4    45.1      45.3   95690500         40.1
#> 10 2007-01-17     45.1     45.3    44.8      44.9  127142600         39.8
#> # ... with 3,409 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don´t know why, but your suggestion seems to convert the date format to character. Easily modified with a mute though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `index()` on the .xts rather than `rownames_to_column()` on the tibble

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)

price.xts <-getSymbols("QQQ", adjustOHLC = TRUE, auto.assign = FALSE)
price<-as_tibble(price.xts)
price$Date <-index(price.xts)

head(price)
tail(price)
```